# Use hosts file for docker-in-docker container in kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

What I want:

Dynamically add hosts in kubernetes pods created by Jenkins master and allow the mounted docker in the pod to use the hosts.

I am using Jenkins to create dynamic slaves for docker build, and created docker-in-docker slave containers for docker build and docker push. The docker-in-docker is created by mounting docker.sock of the VM to the container:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: hostpathvolume
  mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'
```

I am using hostAliases of kubernetes to append the hosts file with some private docker registries:

```
hostAliases:
- ip: 9.110.73.11
  hostnames:
  - devopsprod.icp
- ip: 9.119.42.60
  hostnames:
  - devops.icp
```

I have confirmed that the pods created have these hosts in /etc/hosts, but when I run:

```
docker login -u xxx -p xxx devops.icp:8500
```

I got a DNS error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://devops.icp:8500/v2/: dial tcp: lookup devops.icp on 0.0.0.0:00: no such host
```

This means the docker I run in the container is not using the /etc/hosts in the pod to look up for the ip address. Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to add the hosts manually in the VM's /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

You have mounted `docker.sock` into the Pod, but Docker still uses the configuration from the Node, not from Pod. There are no other options, you need to add aliases to `/etc/hosts` on each Node to make it work.